# Why is my id not getting fetched from my url PHP AJAX MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im trying to grab the my 'id' from the url to load the page however it doesn't seem to be showing anything. 
This is what i have in my url

```
http://localhost/test/product.php?id=21
```

When i use

```
$product_query = "SELECT * FROM photo WHERE photo_id = '21'";
```

it works fine but obviously i want to be able to load any item that is clicked on that has an

from my gallery.php

```
<a href='product.php<?php echo"?id=$photo_id" ?>'>Get this Product!</a>"
```

So this is what i have got from researching but still not results

this is my action.php

```
if(isset($_GET["getProductind"])){

$photo_id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null);

    $product_query = "SELECT * FROM photo WHERE photo_id = '$photo_id'";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($conn,$product_query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
```

And this is what im using in my ajax script

main.js

```
function productind(){
$.ajax({
    url :   "action.php",
    method: "GET",
    data    :   {getProductind:1},
    success :   function(data){
        $("#get_productind").html(data);
    }
})
}
```

Updated hopefully this makes more sense

Comment: `$_GET["getProductind"]` where is that populated from? and how are you using the `productind()` js method?

Comment: look at your developer console and check for errors, what do those throw you back?

Comment: $_GET["getProductind"] was populated from my action.php file. Developer console is showing no errors. I probably should of named each bit of code as a different file so it made more sense

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using `$photo_id = $_GET['id']` to do your query, but in your ajax call you are passing only `getProductind` and no `id` parameter

Answer (score 2):

There are so many errors that's it's even hard to list. I'll give a try.

1- You're using a link:

```
<a href='product.php<?php echo"?id=$photo_id" ?>
```

First, the link is not formatted correctly and is invalid. That aside, the link will request the PHP page directly from the server, and will never call your Ajax code. How are you expecting that to work? You need to use a button. If you really want a link, then you need to disable it and use the `onclick` event to call your function:

```
<a href="javascript:void 0;" onclick="productind()">Get product</a>
```

Then you can put the `id` directly in your `productind()` function. If you prefer to pass the `id` from the link, you can do this:

```
<a href="javascript:void 0;" onclick='productind(<?php echo"$photo_id"?>)'>Get product</a>
```

And you need to add the `id` parameter to the `productind()` function, but I'm not going to show this, because it's pretty trivial.

2- Your Ajax function is not passing the `id` parameter, it is only passing a `getProductind` parameter set to 1. You need to need to add the `id` parameter. Also the URL should be pointing to the `product.php` page not the `action.php` page:

```
function productind() {
    $.ajax({
        url     :   "product.php",
        method  :   "GET",
        data    :   {getProductind: 1, id: <?php echo"$photo_id"?>},
        success :   function(data){
            $("#get_productind").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I cannot comment on your PHP code, because you only posted part of it. That part seems to be fine and will work after you do the above fixes, but I don't know if the rest of the code is returning meaningful data to the Ajax function.